# Dynamic ICS feed, how much data do I need to include?

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

We generate an ICS feed to import calendar items into Google Calendar, etc. Naively, I thought we could just include a couple weeks worth of events each time the feed is fetched, and that GCAL would remember past events that had already been imported. That does not appear to be the case; it appears that GCAL is deleting previously imported events if they do not appear in the current ICS feed. Is this known behavior? Do we need to include every single event for all time in the feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to include everything, always, in your ICS feed. If you want to push events instead, thereby storing the old ones in the users calendar, you have to either send each event by mail with an embedded/attached ICS or use Google Calendars API which requires authorization by every user. We use Cronofy, a paid service, that has a unified api for Office 365, Exchange Server, Gmail and iCloud, when we push events. Using an API instead of ICS also has the benefit that updates are received within seconds, where ICS are only synchronized a few times every day.